# Powershell escape special characters in variable

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to perform a `Copy-Item` on a series of files and I'm noticing that files containing `[` and `]` that are not being copied, however I'm not receiving any error.

I'm using the following function:

```
function fsync ($source,$target) {

    $sourceFiles = @(Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Recurse | select -expand FullName)

    foreach ($f in $sourceFiles) {
        $destFile = $f.Replace($source,$target)
        $exist = Test-Path $destFile

        if ($exist -eq $false) {
            Write-Host "Copying: " $f "to: " $destFile
            Copy-Item -Path "$f" -Destination "$destFile"
        } else {
            Write-Host "File: " $f "Already exists"
        }
    }
}
```

Every time it's run it will print `Copying:  C:\Users\jesse_b\tmp\foo[1].txt to:  C:\Users\jesse_b\tmp\test\foo[1].txt`, and display no error, but the file never actually copies.

I've tried double quoting the variable names but it didn't make a difference.

When I manually copy files with `[` and `]` in them on the terminal it works as long as those characters are escaped.  Is there something I must to do to have my variables treated as literal strings?

Comment: Pass the full object to copy item, instead of expanding the full name property

Comment: @DougMaurer: Still doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weird that it works that way, but I've seen similar results in my own experience.
Use -LiteralPath:

```
Copy-Item -LiteralPath $f.fullname -Destination "$destFile"
```

Comment: Not really that weird, `-Path` allows [wildcards](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_wildcards), while `-LiteralPath` is uh... literal ([Copy-Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item#parameters)).